# Mockito: To test that a returned String is under a given length

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

In Junit I want to check that length of a returned String is under a given length .
I am doing the following and it is passing . But I want to know that is there any better alternate solution it test it.

```
Assertions.assertTrue(roomEntity.getRoomType().length()<=10);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is good. You could use assertThat(), that may be a bit more readable.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThanOrEqualTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

...

assertThat(roomEntity.getRoomType().length(), lessThanOrEqualTo(10));
```

Or refactor the length into its own variable.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThanOrEqualTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

...

int roomTypeLength = roomEntity.getRoomType().length();
assertThat(roomTypeLength, lessThanOrEqualTo(10));
```

Comment: Thank you. By adding Hamcrest dependency to Pom.xml we can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I am following for this.

You can use one of these libraries. Both works the same.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.16.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easytesting/fest-assert -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now to the code segment.

```
Assertions.assertThat(roomEntity.getRoomType().length()).isLessThanOrEqualTo(10);
```

There are some other useful ways are also included in this such as isLessThan, isBetween, hasSize etc.

Comment: Thank you . It was also helpful